# Why chmod gives "Operation not permitted" error?

Tags: linux, permissions, shell

I try to execute `chmod` on a file with Termux, but it sends back an error which I'm unable to solve.
My phone is not rooted. If you can help me I would be most grateful to you for this! Here is the command and the error:

```
$ chmod +x /sdcard/meta-install.sh
chmod: changing permissions of 'meta-install.sh': Operation not permitted
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Android does not allow you to create executable files within the `sdcard` (internal storage, mounted in userspace) partition without root.

A workaround would be to execute the file as `bash meta-install.sh`, assuming it is a bash file. (Alternatively `sh meta-install.sh` to run it using `sh` as the shell).

Comment: Thank you, great advice.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystem on Android's internal memory (called External Storage) is `SDCardFS` (successor of FUSE) which imposes a mask mode (fix permissions) on all files and directories. It's an emulated/virtual filesystem, not the real one. You can only change permissions with `chmod` from `/data/media/` which is the real filesystem (ext4 or f2fs). But `/data/media/` is only accessible to root user.

**Further Reading:**

- [What is /storage/emulated/0?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)

**Related:**

- [Is it possible to change file permissions on Android's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208927/218526)
- [How to remount sdcardfs to allow setting file permisions / ownerships?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/199526/218526)