# Is it possible to change file permissions on Android's internal storage?

Tags: stock-android, file-system, files, file-permissions

How can I change file permission of a file on Android without rooting? I actually want to prevent some files from deletion.

**Note:** I am asking of changing the file permissions of user-created files in internal shared storage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On all operating systems based on Linux kernel - like Android is - it's possible to set permissions on files (including directories) provided that filesystem supports UNIX permissions (uid, gid, mode). Common examples of such filesystems are `ext4` and `f2fs`.

However Android's internal (confusingly called [external](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#InternalVsExternalStorage)) storage which is accessible by installed apps at `/sdcard`, is not an actual but virtual / emulated filesystem exposing `/data/media` (which is a real filesystem) through `sdcardfs`. [sdcardfs](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/refs/heads/android-4.19/fs/sdcardfs/inode.c) and its predecessor `FUSE` expose the emulated filesystem with a fixed set of uid, gid and mask (mode). So the commands `chmod` and `chown` have no impact, whether executed through CLI (adb shell or terminal emulator) or GUI (file explorer).

It's possible to change permission bits of file on underlying actual filesystem, but accessing `/data/media` requires root access because only UID/GID `1023` ([aid_media_rw](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/system/core/include/cutils/android_filesystem_config.h#86)) has read access to the directory. And still the permissions will remain same when viewed from emulated view `/sdcard`.

So you can't change permissions of user created files on Android, with or without root.

**Further reading:**

- [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)

**Related:**

- [Why chmod gives “Operation not permitted” error?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/201605/218526)
- [How to remount sdcardfs to allow setting file permisions / ownerships?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/199526/218526)