# Can't chown or chmod files on android phone

Tags: linux, command-line

Hi there i got some files on my android phone and want to make them executable. Permissions are root:sdcard_rw. I cant remove tha sdcard_rw with chown, and cant make the files executable with chmod.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change file permissions on Android's internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/208906/is-it-possible-to-change-file-permissions-on-androids-internal-storage)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to change the permissions and make things executable by booting into twrp and using its console. Before that i have tried it with termux su and tsu where both had root permissions. Maybe its not a solution but a workaround.